# Stopwatch is not accurate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to JS & jquery. I wrote a stopwatch (accuracy 0.1 second) code very quickly in JS that seems it works correctly up to 10 mins.

The problem is after the 10 min mark it keeps being a couple of seconds behind (I compared it to a digital stopwatch) can anyone see the problem pls?

```
var i = 0,
    desi_s = 0,
    s2 = 0,
    s1 = 0,
    m2 = 0,
    m1 = 0;
$("#start").click(function () {  //calling the start button
    $("#reset").click(function () {  //calling the reset button
        clearInterval(myInt);
        $("#reset").each(function(){
            $(this).html('');    
            this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
            this.style.borderColor = "transparent";
        });
        i = 0;
        desi_s = 0;
        s2 = 0;
        s1 = 0;
        m2 = 0;
        m1 = 0;
        $("#min2 ,#min1 ,#sec2 ,#sec1 ,#desi_sec").html(0);
    })
    i++;
    clearInterval(myInt);
    var myInt = setInterval(function () {
        if (i % 2 !== 0) {
            $("#start").html('stop');

            if (desi_s < 9) {
                desi_s++;
                $("#desi_sec").html(desi_s);
            } else {
                desi_s = 0;
                if (s2 < 9) {
                    s2++;
                    $("#sec2").html(s2);
                } else {
                    s2 = 0;
                    $("#sec2").html(s2);
                    if (s1 < 5) {
                        s1++;
                        $("#sec1").html(s1);
                    } else {
                        s1 = 0;
                        $("#sec1").html(s1);
                        if (m2 < 9) {
                            m2++;
                            $("#min2").html(m2);
                        } else {
                            m2 = 0;
                            $("#min2").html(m2);
                            if (m1 < 5) {
                                m1++;
                                $("#min1").html(m1);
                            } else {
                                m1 = 0;
                                clearInterval(myInt);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        } else {
            clearInterval(myInt);
            $("#start").html('start');
            $("#reset").each(function(){
            $(this).html('reset');    
            this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            this.style.color = "white";
        });
        }
    }, 100);
})
```

Comment: Please try harder next time, use correct grammar and punctuation. Post only the needed code, too much code makes it harder for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't depend on the timing from repeated intervals adding up together very precisely. An interval merely guarantees that a function will be invoked *as soon a possible* after a given time interval has passed, not that it will always happen precisely that often. It makes sense that if you put a bunch of small intervals together that you'll slowly fall behind time.

You should use `performance.now()` as your time base instead. I can't tell you how to use that in the above code in a short post (it would practically take rewriting the code to make it completely clear), but hopefully if you look up `performance.now()` that will get you started.

PS: I'm assuming this is running on a web browser. Node.js doesn't have `performance.now()`, but rather `process.hrtime` which serves a similar function.

Comment: Thank you. I understood where the problem was.